# c# read Byte[] right justify

Tags: c#, .net

i read some Bytestuff and now i try to read Byte[] from the left side. For example:

```
var byteArr = new byte[4]; 
byteArr[0] = 233; 
byteArr[1] = 254; 
byteArr[2] = 4; 
byteArr[3] = 0;
//SHOW IN HEX AS: E9FE0400
```

Now i want to read it from the right side as 4FEE9 is there any function to do this or do i code this function?

Regards 
Rene

Comment: Where are you "showing" this in hex?

Comment: is just an comment for better reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean reversing the array? Just call the `Reverse` method on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932.aspx

Comment: THX FOR YOUR FAST ANSWER. THATS IT!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any build-in method to do this. But you can use `Array.Reverse` for what you need:

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(byteArr.Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Would `Array.Reverse` work for you?

```
Array.Reverse (byteArr); //reverses the elements' order
```